# How does es6 spread operator work on an object to props transformation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I know in order for the `{...todo}` to work in the Todo component, it has to be transformed to props in something like: `completed=false text="clean room"` but how does the spread operator do this? Wouldn't the current `{...todo}` be transformed to `{completed:false}, {text:"clean room"}`?

```
const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map(todo =>
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo}
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
)
```

Comment: It's not an ES operator, it's a JSX operator. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already established, the use of the spread syntax here has nothing to do with ES6, its a JSX construct.

JSX is just syntactic sugar for a `React.createElement` call. The props are actually passed as an object to that function.

You can use the [Babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/) to have a look how the JSX is transformed.

Without spread prop:

```
// In
<Component foo="bar" baz="42" />

// Out
React.createElement(
  Component,
  { foo: "bar", baz: "42" }
);
```

With spread prop:

```
// In
<Component foo="bar" {...xyz} baz="42" />

// Out
React.createElement(
  Component,
  Object.assign({ foo: "bar" }, xyz, { baz: "42" })
);
```

So you can see, if the props contain a spread prop, they are separated into multiple objects and simply merged.

Answer (score 1):

The es6 spread operator indeed works by transforming `{...todo} to {completed:false}`, `{text:"clean room"}`.

However, the same operator is used in JSX but it's not necessarily the same.

From [msdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator),

> The spread syntax allows an expression to be expanded in places where
>   multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for
>   array literals) or multiple variables  (for destructuring assignment)
>   are expected.

Following this idea, the `JSX spread operator` was created. According to the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html),

> The ... operator (or spread operator) is already supported for arrays
>   in ES6. There is also an ECMAScript proposal for Object Rest and
>   Spread Properties. We're taking advantage of these supported and
>   developing standards in order to provide a cleaner syntax in JSX.

Since this already follows the idea of the spread operator, a unification of the two is indeed a welcome idea by the community